# (Ubuntu) Lazarus TCheckListBox When does OnDraw occur?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lazarus, tchecklistbox

Objective: I'm trying to make the first 3 items on a TCheckListBox control appear in bold. lstMenuPermissions is my control.

So I tried this:

```
procedure TfrmPermissions.lstMenuPermissionsDrawItem(Control: TWinControl;
  Index: Integer; ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin      
  if index < 3 Then 
    with (Control as TCheckListBox).Canvas do
      begin
        Font.Bold := True;           
        TextOut(ARect.Left, ARect.Top, (Control as TCheckListBox).Items[Index]);
      end;

end;
```

There was no effect so I thought of checking if the event got fired in the first place and I tried this:

```
procedure TfrmPermissions.lstMenuPermissionsDrawItem(Control: TWinControl;
  Index: Integer; ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  ShowMessage('OK');
end;
```

I have also set the Style to **lbOwnerDrawFixed**.

But there is no message box. So I'm guessing that the event is not firing. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Please advise on how I should get about this.

Thanks!